# Too many nvidia drivers are on my laptop, how should I uninstall them all?

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, uninstall, cuda

I wanted to install cuda and I accidentally installed different versions , but now I want to uninstall them all, how should I do that??

[image]

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

Those drivers shown aren't installed, but they're options that you can install. Judging from your image, the only installed driver is the X.org `Nouveau` driver.

You can't "uninstall all display drivers" if you want to preserve your Desktop GUI. So either you're asking about something else than the screenshot shows, or maybe you think there is an issue, when in fact there isn't.